# run ethereum nodes in Local network windows 10

Tags: go-ethereum

i'm traying to run multiple nodes in my local LAN , i'v setup 3 nodes in 3 windows pc's connected trought the router, all nodes are seted up with the same genesis.json file as fellow :

```
{
  "config": {
    "chainId": 10,
    "homesteadBlock": 0,
    "eip155Block": 0,
    "eip158Block": 0,
    "eip150Block": 0,
    "eip150Hash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
  },
  "alloc": {},
  "coinbase": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "difficulty": "0x0",
  "extraData": "",
  "gasLimit": "0x2fefd8",
  "nonce": "0x0000000000000042",
  "mixhash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "timestamp": "0x00"
}
```

the commande to run each node is :

```
geth --datadir e:/t/node02/ --syncmode "full" --port 30305 --http --http.addr "localhost" --http.port 8546 --http.api "personal,eth,net,web3,txpool,miner" --networkid 99 --identity node02 --nodiscover  --ipcdisable  --allow-insecure-unlock console 2>console2.log
```

the nodes run and i can create accounts and mine
but when i run :

```
admin.addPeer("enode://39d647b98f78eb1081705e135257a489b5145d11753dc65efff735c30097a2a0ed807cdbb101a267212860f54b26e4b6b7d576ec18a8cb5700eade5d98e247f1@105.97.9.234:30304?discport=0")
```

i get true ;
when i run admin.peers , it returns an empty array and peer count is 0.
is this problem related to windows ??! network ? or i'm doing something Wrong ? any help will be appreciated

Comment: The IP used in addPeer isn't a common LAN IP. I'd increase the debug output and look at the interaction between nodes when adding a new peer.

Answer (score 1):

In the start line you have indicated that the nodes start with --port 30305 but in addPeer command specified 30304.
You should check the ports in the startup line and the enode ids (with the admin.nodeInfo.enode command)
And just in case, check with a telnet that the nodes are responding on port 30305.

Comment: the 30304 is to connect to an other node that was runing befor this one